# Devise "Confirmation token is invalid" when user signs up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

Using Rails 4 and Devise 3.1.0 on my web app. I wrote a Cucumber test to test user sign up; it fails when the "confirm my account" link is clicked from the e-mail.

```
Scenario: User signs up with valid data                                                           # features/users/sign_up.feature:9
    When I sign up with valid user data                                                             # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:87
    Then I should receive an email                                                                  # features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:51
    When I open the email                                                                           # features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:76
    Then I should see the email delivered from "no-reply@mysite.com"                                # features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:116
    And I should see "You can confirm your account email through the link below:" in the email body # features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:108
    When I follow "Confirm my account" in the email                                                 # features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:178
    Then I should be signed in                                                                      # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:142
      expected to find text "Logout" in "...Confirmation token is invalid..." (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
     ./features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:143:in `/^I should be signed in$
```

This error is reproducible when I sign up manually through the web server as well, so it doesn't appear to be a Cucumber issue.

I would like:

- The user to be able to one-click confirm their account through this e-mail's link
- Have the user stay signed in after confirming their account

I have setup:

- The latest Devise code, from GitHub (3.1.0, ref 041fcf90807df5efded5fdcd53ced80544e7430f)
- A `User` class that implements `confirmable`
- Using the 'default' confirmation controller (I have not defined my own custom one.)

I have read these posts:

- [Devise confirmation_token is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390080/devise-confirmation-token-is-invalid)
- [Devise 3.1: Now with more secure defaults](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/)
- [GitHub Issue - Devise confirmation_token invalid](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2587)

And have tried:

- Setting `config.allow_insecure_tokens_lookup = true` in my Devise initializer, which throws an 'unknown method' error on startup. Plus it sounds like this is only supposed to be a temporary fix, so I'd like to avoid using it.
- Purged my DB and started from scratch (so no old tokens are present)

**Update:**

Checking the confirmation token stored on the `User` after registering. The emails token matches the DBs token. According to the posts above, the new Devise behavior says not supposed to, and that instead it is should generate a second token based on the e-mail's token. *This is suspicious.* Running `User.confirm_by_token('[EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_TOKEN]')` returns a User who has errors set "@messages={:confirmation_token=>["is invalid"]}", which appears to be the source of the issue.

Mismatching tokens seems to be the heart of the issue; running the following code in console to manually change the User's confirmation_token causes confirmation to succeed:

```
new_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(User, :confirmation_token, '[EMAIL_TOKEN]')
u = User.first
u.confirmation_token = new_token
u.save
User.confirm_by_token('[EMAIL_TOKEN]') # Succeeds
```

So why is it saving the wrong confirmation token to the DB in the first place? I am using a custom registration controller... maybe there's something in it that causes it to be set incorrectly?

**routes.rb**

```
  devise_for  :users,
          :path => '',
          :path_names => {
            :sign_in => 'login',
            :sign_out => 'logout',
            :sign_up => 'register'
            },
          :controllers => {
            :registrations => "users/registrations",
            :sessions => "users/sessions"
          }
```

**users/registrations_controller.rb**:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    # Custom code to fix DateTime issue
    Utils::convert_params_date_select params[:user][:profile_attributes], :birthday, nil, true

    super
  end

  def sign_up_params
    # TODO: Still need to fix this. Strong parameters with nested attributes not working.
    #       Permitting all is a security hazard.
    params.require(:user).permit!
    #params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_attributes)
  end
  private :sign_up_params
end
```

Comment: Does the base url in your confirmation email match your local server?  E.g. if it's supposed to be `localhost:3000` is that what you're sending in the email?

Comment: Yes, my site is running at `mysite.com:3000`, its config is set to `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mysite.com:3000' }` and the e-mail link directs to `mysite.com:3000`.

Comment: So when you're running in development and testing modes, you are doing so at `mysite.com:3000` for both?

Comment: Development uses my local web server `mysite.com:3000` which is a host file redirect to `localhost`. Test actually uses Cucumber/Capybara/Poltergeist/PhantomJS to run the application and email_spec to dance around the need for an actual web server; I'm confident the test environment is fine, considering the issue is reproducible in my development environment anyways.

Comment: Looks like I've bumped into the [same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661663/upgrading-to-devise-3-01-getting-reset-password-token-is-invalid), but with password reset.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

So upgrading to Devise 3.1.0 left some 'cruft' in a view that I hadn't touched in a while.

According to [this blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/), you need to change your Devise mailer to use `@token` instead of the old `@resource.confirmation_token`.

Find this in `app/views/<user>/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb` and change it to something like:

```
<p>Welcome <%= @resource.email %>!</p>
<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token) %></p>
```

This should fix any token-based confirmation problems you're having. This is likely to fix any unlock or reset password token problems as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really did not understood what was going on! Many changes by the way, the article is very helpful.

Comment: Thank you, @Dave! The same holds true for the password reset template. Change to `link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token)`

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/2a8d0f9beeb31cd2287094c5dcf843d0bd069eb8/app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb#L5

Comment: ...and same thing for `unlock_instructions.html` template

Comment: @scarver2 's comment should be part of the answer as well! Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: This doesn't really explain what's happening though. I'm trying to do a `visit user_confirmation_path(confirmation_token: user.confirmation_token)` from a test, and after reading this I guess I need to figure out how to create `@token`. Did you ever get to the bottom of what was actually happening under the covers @david-elner?

Comment: [I wrote an issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2615) on the Devise GitHub page with a full explanation of why it was happening. There's more discussion and an explanation from the gem author there, too.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine just found this question and emailed me asking if I had figured this out, which reminded me that I never submitted my own answer, so here goes :)

I ended up resetting the token & using `send` to get the raw token. It's ugly, but it works in a punch for `devise (3.5.1)`.

```
26   it "should auto create org" do
27     email = FG.generate :email
28     visit new_user_registration_path
29     fill_in :user_name, with: 'Ryan Angilly'
30     fill_in :user_user_provided_email, with: email
31     fill_in :user_password, with: '1234567890'
32 
33     expect do
34       click_button 'Continue'
35     end.to change { Organization.count }.by(1)
36 
37     expect(page.current_path).to eq(confirmation_required_path)
38     u = User.where(email: email).first
39     u.send :generate_confirmation_token
40     email_token = u.instance_variable_get(:@raw_confirmation_token)
41     u.save!
42     os = u.organizations
43     expect(os.size).to eq(1)
44     visit user_confirmation_path(confirmation_token: email_token)
45     o = os.first
46 
47     u.reload
48     expect(u.confirmed?)
49     expect(page.current_url).to eq(organization_getting_started_url(o))
50   end
```

Answer (score 0):

As of devise 3.5.2, the confirmation token is no longer digested during the confirmation process. This means that the token in the email will match the token in the database.

I was still having trouble with confirmations after figuring this out, but in my case it turned out to be a bug I introduced when I overrode `find_first_by_auth_conditions`. By fixing the bug I introduced in that method, I fixed my errors with confirmation.