# Upgrading to devise 3.1 => getting Reset password token is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec2

**Solution**

Thanks to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/stevenharman/6227508) form Steven Harman, I got it working.
devise_mail_helpers.rb

```
module Features
  module MailHelpers

    def last_email
      ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[0]
    end

    # Can be used like:
    #  extract_token_from_email(:reset_password)
    def extract_token_from_email(token_name)
      mail_body = last_email.body.to_s
      mail_body[/#{token_name.to_s}_token=([^"]+)/, 1]
    end

  end
end
```

I added the file `devise_mail_helpers.rb` to the same folder as the features specs and wrote this spec.

```
require 'devise_mail_helpers.rb'
include Features
include MailHelpers
describe "PasswordResets" do
  it "emails user when requesting password reset" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit root_url
    find("#login_link").click
    click_link "Forgot your password?"
    fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
    click_button "Send instructions"
    current_path.should eq('/users/sign_in')
    page.should have_content("You will receive an email with instructions about how to reset your password in a few minutes.")
    last_email.to.should include(user.email)
    token = extract_token_from_email(:reset_password) # Here I call the MailHelper form above
    visit edit_password_url(reset_password_token: token)
    fill_in "user_password", :with => "foobar"
    fill_in "user_password_confirmation", :with => "foobar1"
    find('.signup_firm').find(".submit").click
    page.should have_content("Password confirmation doesn't match Password")
  end
 end
```

This takes care of the specs, to make it work in the browser look at Dave's answer below.

**Original Question**

In my rails 4 app, I've upgraded devise to 3.1 and ran `rails s`, then I got this:

```
`raise_no_secret_key': Devise.secret_key was not set. 
 Please add the following to your Devise initializer: (RuntimeError)
 config.secret_key = '--secret--'
```

I added the secret key to the devise initializer.

After this I get the following error when I try to reset the password

```
Reset password token is invalid
```

It seems like the token that gets sent in the email is not correct. Everything else is working. I logging in and out like a warm knife trough butter.

**Update**

Now I guess that it's got to be something with the encryption of the `reset_password_token` Here from the feature spec:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, 
 :reset_password_token => "something", 
 :reset_password_sent_at => 1.hour.ago)
visit edit_password_url(user, :reset_password_token => 
  user.reset_password_token)
fill_in "user_password", :with => "foobar"
click_button "Change my password"
page.should have_content("Password confirmation doesn't match Password")
```

the error occured is:

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_content
("Password confirmation doesn't match Password")        
expected to find text "Password confirmation doesn't match Password" in 
"Reset password token is invalid"
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You commented on [my similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626544/devise-confirmation-token-is-invalid-when-user-signs-up/18675155#18675155) a bit ago, and I found an answer that might help you as well.

Upgrading to Devise 3.1.0 left some 'cruft' in a view that I hadn't touched in a while. According to [this blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/), you need to change your Devise mailer to use `@token` instead of the old `@resource.confirmation_token`.

Find this in `app/views/<user>/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb` and change it to something like:

```
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>
<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password, and you can do this through the link below.</p>
<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @token) %></p>
<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

This should fix any token-based confirmation problems you're having. This is likely to fix any unlock or confirmation token problems as well.

Comment: This is the correct solution to make it work om the browser, but how to test it?

Comment: At a glance, your Rspec test above looks like it should do the trick. Assuming the 'invalid token' problem is gone, and if it's failing at a specific spot, you should share the error. Strategically speaking, combining Rspec or Cucumber with email_spec should allow you to automatically test this. My linked question and [this wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Cucumber) have more information about how to test Devise with Cucumber.

Comment: the test is passing. Before I fixed the problem it was failing with 'invalid token'.

Comment: If you are using custom mailer you have to provide the token to the views by   

def reset_password_instructions(user, token, opts={})
    @token = token
.....

Answer (score 8):

FYI, if you're trying to send a reset password token via another means (i.e. different mailer), you can use code like this (dug out of Devise source), in your User class:

```
def send_invitation
  raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(self.class, :reset_password_token)

  self.reset_password_token   = enc
  self.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
  self.save(:validate => false)

  Notifier.signup_notification(contactable: self, token: raw).deliver
end
```

Comment: The key is `self.reset_password_token = enc`, and setting `@token = raw`. Thank you so much~!

Answer (score 7):

I guess you've upgraded Devise to v3.1 not v3.01, because of `config.secret_key`. So I think it is somehow related to new devise feature - secret key.
I found two commits for secret key feature that can be helpful to better understanding:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/32648027e282eb4c0f4f42e9c9cc0c961765faa8
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/d56641f514f54da04f778b2a9b816561df7910c2

Probably you will find something useful for you on http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/ as well.
Also you can grep **reset_password_token** on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/compare/v3.0...v3.1.0.

**EDIT**
Read on http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/:

- The Devise mailer now receives one extra token argument on each
  method. If you have customized the Devise mailer, you will have to
  update it. ***All mailers views also need to be updated to use
  @token***, as shown [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/2a8d0f9beeb31cd2287094c5dcf843d0bd069eb8/app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb#L5), instead of getting the token directly from
  the resource;

Comment: Thanks! I've investigated a bit more. I know of the changes to the token handling in Devise. So, I got to work in the browser. But, how to test it?. There are some tips in the comment on the [blog](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/).By the way I corrected the 3.01 typo to 3.1.

Answer (score 7):

I had this error on specs. I was trying to manually set `reset_password_token` on User so I could just pass in the token to the `edit_user_password_path`. However, the reset tokens are hashed, so setting it manually won't work. Oops! To avoid this error, I set `reset_token` equal to the actual token generated which is returned by `user.send_reset_password_instructions`.

Working spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'User resets password' do
  scenario 'fills out reset form' do
    user = create(:user)
    reset_token = user.send_reset_password_instructions
    new_password = 'newpassword!'
    visit edit_user_password_path(user, reset_password_token: reset_token)

    fill_in :user_password, with: new_password
    fill_in :user_password_confirmation, with: new_password
    click_button 'Change my password'

    expect(page).to have_content(
      'Your password was changed successfully. You are now signed in.'
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted: the reason is that the view which generates the mail which includes the reset password link needs to be changed.

I saw this error because I was still using the `devise-i18n-views` gem, which generates the old link. Removing that gem and relying on the views which are now a part of the `devise-i18n` gem solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your devise reset password template make sure following content should correct:

=link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @token)