# Rails 3.2 error overriding devise for email only signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, confirmation

I have been trying to follow https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation in order to allow users on my app to supply only an email address when they sign up, and then be prompted for the remainder of their information after they confirm their email.  But the approach seems to be slightly broken or I don't fully understand it.

In the instructions, in the confirmations_controller there is this method:

```
  def with_unconfirmed_confirmable
    original_token = params[:confirmation_token]
    confirmation_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(User, :confirmation_token, original_token)
    @confirmable = User.find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:confirmation_token, confirmation_token)
    if !@confirmable.new_record?
      @confirmable.only_if_unconfirmed {yield}
    end
  end
```

If I leave it as is, I always get a "Confirmation Token is Invalid" error.  It appears to be due to the new token being generated and not found.  You can see what I mean in the log:

```
Started GET "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=9835abdff3d03d0a29e1c5a640c6a22f1ed6289b4cf696ed514ba183aad49caa" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-12 07:39:42 -0700
Processing by ConfirmationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"confirmation_token"=>"9835abdff3d03d0a29e1c5a640c6a22f1ed6289b4cf696ed514ba183aad49caa"}
  ESC[1mESC[36mUser Load (0.3ms)ESC[0m  ESC[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = '98e17d2ea3cc3fcba5cab7d37bd9a865fc2e318372cb293b541b8a05b46f
e4a3' LIMIT 1ESC[0m
```

But if I change the method to use the original_token instead of the generated confirmation_token, it all works.  What am I missing?  Should I be worried about not using the derived token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was because my app was on an older version of devise that inadvertently got upgraded to devise 3.1.  Thanks to this post: [Upgrading to devise 3.1 => getting Reset password token is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661663/upgrading-to-devise-3-1-getting-reset-password-token-is-invalid)

I updated the mailer to send the correct token and now all is working.