# Confirmation token can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mysql2

Earlier i was getting - token not found .After making changes advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626544/devise-confirmation-token-is-invalid-when-user-signs-up) i am getting this new error

Confirmation token can't be blank.

Using rails - 3.0.6
devise - 1.1.3
ruby - 1.9.3

Been banging my head since hours and i am still clueless why the token isn't getting received . This happens only after the user clicks on confirmation link sent via mail . Any pointers what i should be doing.  Please help , thanks in advance .

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # TODO:  Remove talent_seeker from here, set manually on creation
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :disabled,
    :job_title, :company_name, :city, :state, :zip, :public_profile, :willing_to_relocate, :avatar, :resume, 
    :remove_avatar, :remove_resume, :html_resume_attributes, :upload_in_progress, :rb_resume
```

end

Comment: Do you get this error for an existing user or for newly created users?

Comment: It's a client app and i just hosted in local , no users yet .

Comment: Would you please post the user model? Or if you can't, check if there are any callbacks that tries to save the model somehow?

Comment: Any chance that you override Devise ConfirmationsController?

Comment: Haven't seen yet as such

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47833/discussion-between-caffeine-coder-and-ahmad-sherif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply the solution from the question you've mentioned due to devise version incompatibility. Just replace the last line in your `app/views/<user>/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb` with the following line

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

Comment: thanks again for taking so much trouble to solve it :)

Comment: can u take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931171/rails-amazon-production-error