# Rails Amazon production error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am running my ruby on rails app (rails 3.0.6 , ruby 1.9.3) on amazon server , on user sign up it shows the error - Something went wrong

Updated log

> Started POST "/job_seeker/sign_up" for 122.169.118.210 at 2014-02-19
>   15:12:30 +0000   Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML 
>   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"EJz60o29u5pXTOv7+gO/sVDXyGhVcHuM8Iezn5daKlI=",
>   "user"=>{"first_name"=>"kumar", "last_name"=>"pathak",
>   "email"=>"kumardevp@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"} Rendered
>   devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (0.5ms)
>
> Sent mail to kumardevp@gmail.com (141ms) Completed   in 297ms
>
> Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not
>   accepted. Learn more at ):
>   app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:16:in `create'
>
> Started GET "/users/password/new" for 122.169.118.210 at 2014-02-19
>   15:13:00 +0000   Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#new as HTML
>   Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.5ms) Rendered
>   layouts/application.html.erb (6.0ms) Rendered
>   devise/passwords/new.html.erb within layouts/content (10.7ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 120ms (Views: 119.1ms | ActiveRecord: 11.5ms)

Running `tail -f log/production.log` shows

> Started GET "/" for 122.169.118.210 at 2014-02-19 15:13:08 +0000
>   Processing by MainController#index as HTML Rendered
>   main/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6.0ms) Completed 200
>   OK in 7ms (Views: 6.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
>
> Started GET "/" for 122.169.118.210 at 2014-02-19 15:48:16 +0000
>   Processing by MainController#index as HTML Rendered
>   main/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.9ms) Completed 200
>   OK in 7ms (Views: 6.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Here is my `index.html.erb` code

```
<div id="banner">
        <script language="javascript">
                if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
                        alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
                } else {
                        AC_FL_RunContent(
                                'codebase', '',
                                'width', '713',
                                'height', '279',
                                'src', 'slideshow',
                                'quality', 'high',
                                'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
                                'align', 'middle',
                                'play', 'true',
                                'loop', 'true',
                                'scale', 'showall',
                                'wmode', 'window',
                                'devicefont', 'false',
                                'id', 'slideshow',
                                'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
                                'name', 'slideshow',
                                'menu', 'true',
                                'allowFullScreen', 'false',
                                'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
                                'movie', 'slideshow',
                                'salign', ''
                                ); //end AC code
                }
        </script>
        <noscript>
                <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="640" height="466" id="slideshow" align="middle">
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
                <param name="movie" value="slideshow.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />       <embed src="slideshow.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="713" height="279" name="slideshow" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
                </object>
                 </noscript>
</div>
<div id="modulelist">
        <div class="moduletable">
                <h3>Are You Seeking a Job?</h3>
                <p>Job seekers can create an iTAG, post
                their resume, and manage their content in a user-friendly environment.</p>
                <%= link_to "Find a job", new_job_seeker_registration_path, :class => "readon" %>
        </div>
        <div class="moduletable last">
                <h3>Are You Seeking Help?</h3>
                <p>App offers employers and job seekers the perfect forum for identifying and connecting with successful matches.</p>
                <%= link_to "Find a new job", new_talent_seeker_registration_path, :class => "readon" %>
        </div>

</div>
```

I am not getting any pointers as to what i may possibly be doing wrong , please help or any suggestions are welcome . Thanks in advance .

Comment: The log you posted is not very helpful, it would be better if you added more log entries till the error happens.

Comment: wait a second , will do

Comment: also wen i open the production link in chrome , it shows a https error and asks me to get certificate . Are they related ?

Comment: Well, there you have it, something's wrong with the SMTP authentication. Please check the username and/or password you got in `config/environments/production.rb`.

Comment: Not sure about the certificate thing yet, but it's better to solve one thing at a time.

Comment: :authentication => "login" - should i change this ?

Comment: Can't say that you should, it really depends on the SMTP server that you're using.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48059/discussion-between-caffeine-coder-and-ahmad-sherif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't the one that got showed in the error . Had to re-install passenger , nginx to newer versions to directly take in changes at server . The tcp socket wasn't configured at server properly too , so with help of Ahmad Sherif , i was able to solve the problem finally . What i learnt from this is that i should get more exposure to puma, thin & unicord servers too as depending on one server doesn't helps in times of panic .