# Why I can't confirm un-confirmed accounts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In my rails app, I discovered that the key `:confirmable` was not included in the user model, so when I added it, users will have to confirm their email now, what happen is like the following:

1. user tries to sign in, he will get an error:

   You have to confirm your account before continuing.
   And a link:

   Didn't receive confirmation instructions?
2. user clicks on the link `Didn't receive confirmation instructions?` and fills his email
3. a confirmation email is sent, but when user clicks on the link he get an error:

   Some errors were found, please take a look:

But, there is no details about the error, and even in the server logs, there is nothing useful, only:

```
cache: [GET /en/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=14d82c74793ca19a58aff93d328fb4b06a7c8da53aef79a82c140a95e7cf7f4a] pass
```

So, how can I get more useful error, or how can I can debug this?

Comment: did you create and ran the migrations too?

Comment: Does it work (`confirmable` email link) for a newly signed up user, I mean totally new user?

Comment: migrations are all migrated, I will check if totally new user will have a confirmation email

Comment: I confirm that the problem also happens for totally new users

Comment: @simo can you share your email view?

Comment: I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626544/devise-confirmation-token-is-invalid-when-user-signs-up